# Can I run/debug Heroku Node.js app locally with VSCode?

Tags: node.js, heroku, visual-studio-code

---

### TL; DR

On [Microsoft VSCode v1.6.1](https://code.visualstudio.com), how to:

1. Properly set runtime executable?
2. Properly pass [Heroku arguments](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local)?
3. Run [Heroku Node.js](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/nodejs) app?
4. Debug [Heroku Node.js](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/nodejs) app?

---

### Details

I have created a [Heroku Node.js](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/nodejs) application, which is launched using the CLI command:

```
heroku local web
```

and successfully starts at port 5000.

I am trying to debug it using [Microsoft Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), using the following [`launch.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/runtimes/nodejs) configuration:

```
{
    "name": "Launch",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/app.js",
    "stopOnEntry": false,
    "args": [],
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "preLaunchTask": null,
    "runtimeExecutable": "/usr/local/bin/heroku",
    "runtimeArgs": [
        "local web",
    ],
    "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "development"
    },
    "console": "internalConsole",
    "sourceMaps": false,
    "outFiles": []
}
```

But VSCode is automagically passing `--debug-brk` argument to heroku, causing the error:

```
/usr/local/bin/heroku --debug-brk=23080 'local web' app.js 
    !    `--debug-brk=23080` is not a heroku command.
    !    See `heroku help` for a list of available commands.
```

VSCode also does not find heroku command without its full path (seems like it is not loading `PATH` environment variable).

Any ideas about how to setup the editor?

Answer (score 3):

The following solution works for me:

1) In your procfile add the parameter --debug to the node process

```
web: node --debug server.js
```

By default the debugger listens in the port 5858

2) Once you have the node process running, open VSCode and add the following configuration to your launch.json file

```
{
 "type": "node",
 "request": "attach",
 "name": "Attach to Process",
 "port": 5858
}
```

3) Finally, click the play button in VSCode with the option "Attach to Process" and it should debug your process.

Comment: Getting an error with this Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5858. Pretty sure I have not changed any defaults... I run my node process on port 9000, but that is not the debugger process.

Comment: Clear and concise explanation which sorted it for me! 

Just to add a little clarification for naive node users like myself: adding the _--inspect_ parameter to the Procfile mean that when the Node app starts an additional Node process running on a different port, which can be attached to by a debugger, spins up. My web app runs on port 8080 and the additional debugging process was 9229.

Answer (score 3):

The following solution worked for me.
In my package.json "scripts", I added:

```
 "debug": "node --inspect-brk server.js"
```

Then, in launch.json I added an [envFile](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_load-environment-variables-from-external-file-node) entry to the default "Launch via NPM" configuration, which now looks looks like this:

```
 {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch via NPM",
        "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "run-script",
            "debug"
        ],
        "port": 9229,
        "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"
}
```

The above solution enables the VSCode debugger to run my server via an npm script, and my server runs with the env vars set in my .gitignore'd .env file, just like in the "regular" [Heroku node.js workflow](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_load-environment-variables-from-external-file-node).

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this as for some reason the solution propsed didn't work for me. However, an alternate solution did so I thought I would share.

From the default debugging options in VS Code choose 

`Attach by Process ID`

When you start the debugger with this configuration it should list available processes to attach to and one should be simply be server.js. This requires manually attaching each time, and if the other automatic attachment works for you that may be better, but this is still a workable solution.